# Partitioning failed

Tags: wubi, installation

I was installing Ubuntu with Wubi off a USB stick, and the demo launched fine and everything so I decided to install Ubuntu for dual boot. So while installing I guess that partition failed cause it was stuck on creating et4.

I closed down Ubuntu and started up Windows and when I looked at my hard drive space it went from ~168 GB down to ~86 GB. So I am guessing it did partition but Ubuntu must have not installed correctly.

When I boot my PC It goes straight to Windows, and if I go to the boot menu it also shows Ubuntu If I have my USB plugged in. Is there anyway to correct this so I can get my HDD space back? I gave about 92 GB for Ubuntu on the partition.

Comment: I also went to my disk management and it won't let me expand my main partition.

Comment: Wait. Did you use Wubi or did you use standard partitions?

Comment: I just used Wubi. Wubi said nothing about partitioning your drive before I installed it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you used Wubi to install Ubuntu, you can use Windows' Add/Remove Programs tool to uninstall Ubuntu.

Also, I believe that Wubi uses file instead of partitions. So, you should be able to find the partition file somewhere. I guess you could search for large files or something. I'm no Windows expert and have never personally used Wubi, so I can't be more specific.